# API for outlook.com

Tags: .net, api, outlook, hotmail, outlook.com

Is there a current or planned API for retrieving or sending email through outlook.com?  I can't seem to find if this is or will be supported through POP, IMAP, Exchange or what.  The [Live Connect Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/) doesn't seem to mention outlook.com yet.

Comment: I have read that Hotmail and Live.com are same thing in a blog. When I clicked on developer link in bottom I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live//default.aspx hope this have something interesting for you.

Comment: Hey @Tim, what you means send or get email through outlook.com? if you try to send mail in your code by outlook.com then it's also use smtp server of outlook.co.

Comment: outlook.com is just a UI which is used email address hosted in Hotmail or outlook.com itself. if you use hotmail.com service it's make you also use outlook.com services.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it means anything now, but Microsoft has released what we need

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826535

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a lot (it's all pretty new)

[A reference to Azure and the Outlook.com app marketplace](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devschool/archive/2012/08/01/developing-outlook-com-well-back-from-whatever-july-was-and-outlook-com-appears-impact-on-windows-8-win8.aspx)

[And an MSDN reference that looks promising but doesn't state anything about Outlook.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/exchange/821c8eb9-bb58-42e8-9a3a-61ca635cba59) but my bet is you can use these APIs to connect to Outlook.com too (or soon)

Comment: +1, thanks for the references. It could be a while before we have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Outlook.com now supports IMAP](http://blogs.office.com/2013/09/12/outlook-com-now-has-imap/).

[MSDN Reference for Outlook.com IMAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/dn440163.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

While this may not be the whole answer for everyone, my Palm came up with these settings on its own, and they seem to work:

Incoming mail server:

- pop3.live.com
- SSL encryption
- Port 995

Outgoing mail server:

- smtp.live.com
- Use authentication: on
- TLS encryption
- Port 587

This seems to agree with the community info provided in [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/mail-sync/are-there-pop3-settings-for-outlookcom/8515bbdb-14bd-487b-86c1-bea3edf6a24f).